# Why am I getting unexpected output?

Tags: c++

This is my C++ program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()  
{ 
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  if(a-- > 0 || ++b > 2){
     cout << "stage1 -inside if";
  }
  else{
     cout << "stage2 -inside else";
  }
  cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

When I execute this program on codeblock or an online compiler, the output is:

> stage1 -inside if0 2

When I am doing a dry run of this program, I expect the below output:

> stage1 -inside if0 3

Can anyone explain why I am getting a different output than my expected output?

Comment: what does "doing dry run" mean exactly?

Comment: Short circuit boolean expression evaluation. Worth a google. `++b>2` is not evaluated because `a-->0` is already true, therefore `true || <anything>` is also true.

Answer (score 1):

"dry run" - I suppose you mean it is what result you expect in your mind?

Do you know that the logical operator `||` does not evaluate the right part if the left part is true?

```
a-->0 || ++b>2
```

`a--` is evaluated first, `a` gets 0, `a--` returns 1, that is greater than zero and `a-- > 0` is true. Thus, `++b > 2`, particularly `++b` are not evaluated, and the correct output is

```
stage1 -inside if0 2
```

Comment: ok, and what if I use '&&' operator instead of ' || ' operator, will output be same ?

Comment: Just try it. The output will be another. `&&` does not evaluate the right part if the left part is false. Any good C++ book explains this.